# How to use if statement within IMongoCollection.Find() method?

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda

I have two different filter options for the Find() method depending on the value of the parameter. So I want to combine them in one lambda function.

It is easy to write separate methods for each options:

```
            if (status == null)
            {
                var dbOrders = orderCollection
                    .Find(t => true)
                    .ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                var dbOrders = orderCollection
                    .Find(t => t.Status==status)
                    .ToList();
            }
```

Obviously, it is not the best way to do. I think it can be done within one lambda function.
I have tried something like that, but it seems that it is not correct

```
var dbOrders = orderCollection
                    .Find(t => status == null: true ? t.Status==status)
                    .ToList();
```

What is the correct way to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you want to combine it if the first one does nothing? You can simply keep your `if` statement and run `var dbOrders = orderCollection.ToList();` when `status == null`

Comment: This comment is the correct answer, because Find is a extension method of IMongocollection that does not return an IEnumerable. So chaining is not possible like IEnumerable.Where